# serialize a primitive_type class using polymorphic_text_archive in boost

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I am trying to test the following sample code which explains how to serialize a user defined primitive type class in boost,it works fine.But if I switch to polymorphic_archive (testing with polymorphic_text_*) which I will have to use in my project, it fails to compile and I am struggling to fix it(testing in vc++2008).

All the code can be found in the below 3 links: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/test/test_primitive.cpp http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/test/test_tools.hpp and libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/test/text_archive.hpp

Please change the headers and typedefs in the text_archive.hpp to polymorphic ones as follows to get the error:

```
    #include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_oarchive.hpp>
    typedef boost::archive::polymorphic_text_oarchive test_oarchive;  
    #include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_iarchive.hpp>  
    typedef boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive test_iarchive;
```

Preprocessor flags used :

BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK;BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED;BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3

Error message:

> ------ Build started: Project: TestSer4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   Compiling...
>   test_primitive.cpp
>   c:\program files\boost\boost_1_46_1\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(88) : error 
>   C2664: 'void boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive_impl::save(const bool)' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from 'const A' to 'const bool'
>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion,
>   or the operator cannot be called
>          c:\program files\boost\boost_1_46_1\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(232) :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void 
>   boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Archive=boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive,
>              T=A
>          ]
>          c:\program files\boost\boost_1_46_1\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(308) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type::save_primitive::invoke(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Archive=boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive,
>              T=A
>          ]
>          c:\program files\boost\boost_1_46_1\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(525) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type::invoke(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Archive=boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive,
>              T=A
>          ]
>          c:\program files\boost\boost_1_46_1\boost\archive\polymorphic_oarchive.hpp(122) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::save(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Archive=boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive,
>              T=A
>          ]
>          c:\program files\boost\boost_1_46_1\boost\archive\detail\interface_oarchive.hpp(63) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive_impl::save_override(const boost::serialization::nvp &,int)' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              T=A
>          ]
>          c:\program files\boost\boost_1_46_1  \boost\archive\detail\polymorphic_oarchive_route.hpp(171) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive::operator <<(T &)' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              Archive=boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive,
>              T=const boost::serialization::nvp
>          ]
>          c:\apps\proj\serilization\testser4\testser4\test_primitive.cpp(73) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive &boost::archive::detail::polymorphic_oarchive_route::operator <<>(const boost::serialization::nvp &)' being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              ArchiveImplementation=boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl,
>              T=A
>          ]
>   Build log was saved at "file://C:\apps\proj\Serilization\BusSchedEx\BusSchedEx\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
>   TestSer4 - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use polymorphic archives together with `boost::serialization::primitive_type`. See [this Boost ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5679) for an explanation.

IMO this is a real unfixable conceptual bug in the whole boost::serialization idea.